# iTextSharp add pre-existing PDF as a layer to another PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have reports that are being converted into PDFs. Some of these reports have information missing simply because we don't track it. I have created another PDF with the shell of the report and placed input fields controls on it. I would like to know if there is a way to apply the shell PDF to the converted PDF so users can enter information in those blank fields without having to print them out and hand write them? I have done this manually through Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.3 by applying the generated PDF to the shell PDF as a **Layer**. I have done as much poking around with iTextSharp concerning **Layers**, but I still haven't found anything that has worked.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What about using iTextSharp to 'draw' the text information onto the 'converted' PDFs rather than trying to layer two pdf pages together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Layers won't work with fields.  PDF Layers are a part of the page contents.  Form fields, as with all annotations, float above the page.

2) Having said that, you can hide and reveal form fields using Acrobat/Reader JavaScript.  The "doc" object is usually "this" in field and page entry points, so to show a given field, it's just:

```
var fld = this.getField("fieldName");
fld.hidden = false;
```

There are quite a few different places you can add JS to a PDF.  Various field events, page events, and document events.  You can also set a layer's action to some javaScript.  Heck you can set a bookmark's action to be javascript instead of a "go over there" action.

Note that layers are called "Optional Content Groups" (OCGs) in PDF tech-speak.  If you *really* want to create a layer, it looks like it would go something like this:

```
// layer implements PdfOCG
PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("MyLayer", writer);

PdfContentByte cb = getAContentByteFromSomewhere();

cb.beginLayer(layer); // takes PDFOCG object

/* draw stuff to be part of that layer */

cb.endLayer();
```

There are a number of examples on the iText site corresponding to "iText In Action, 2nd edition" (I don't get paid, the author is a friend).  [The aforementioned examples can be found here](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=460).

This bears repeating:  Fields cannot be part of an OCG (layer).  They can however be scripted to act like they are.